# "Command not found" message while executing "hadoop namenode -format"

Tags: software-installation, hadoop

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) for my hadoop setup up to "Format the new Hadoop File System" and I get the "Command not found" message when I enter

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you perhaps miss the step where you `source` the modified `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: I didn't miss it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-do everything from the beginning. It may be possible that you have not set the path properly. As the output says `Command not found`, this means hadoop has not been installed properly.

Comment: That would be a lot of rework... any suggestion what I would be missing. I will try a few times and if doesn't work then I will go and redo from the start

Comment: repeat "Install Hadoop" section

Comment: I got this figured out, I was the doing the wrong mapping..Its working now

Answer (score 4):

In your `~/.bashrc`, instead of writing

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
```

change it to

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
```

I was facing the same issue for a long time. This worked for me.

Or try this:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

If you want to use hadoop command without specifying the path you can edit your `~/.bashrc` file. If you have alredy done it, reopen your terminal and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I also did the same installation and actually the path is `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop/` 
so you should move everything from `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/` to `/usr/local/hadoop` so that the `hadoop` command will work.

Command to move everything is

```
mv -v /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/* /usr/local/hadoop
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If path is correct and still facing the error

then

after adding path variables in ~/.bashrc

run this command source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Set your path:

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add to end:

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX="/usr/local/hadoop/"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
```

Then,

`source /etc/profile`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your environment variables are set correctly and HADOOP can find JAVA. And Include both in your PATH.
Assuming you have Java and Hadoop under /usr/local/ like me,

Add these to the very end of your ~./bashrc file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_171
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=${PATH}:${HADOOP_INSTALL}/bin:${HADOOP_HOME}/bin
```